# Filter, Sort and Paginate after Fractal Transform

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, collections

I'm using **Fractal transformer** in **Laravel 5.6**

I have a News Model and User Model. News model has a foreign key user_id. when I want to show list of News I transform the data like below:

```
public function transform(News $news)
{
    return [
        'identifier' => (int) $news->id,
        'title' => (string) $news->title,
        'content' => (string) $news->content,
        'user' => (String) $news->user->f_name . " " . $news->user->l_name,
        'userType' => (String) $news->user->user_type,
        'likeCount' => (int) $news->likes,
    ];
}
```

And transform function is:

```
protected function transformData($data, NewsTransformer $transformer) {
    $transformation = fractal($data, new $transformer);
    return $transformation->toArray();
}
```

Now the problem is that when I transform the list of news it returns array instead of collection and after transformation I cant use operations like filtering the data by userType or sorting the data by user.

So how can I sort, filter and paginate the results by new fields after transformation?

Comment: you can wrap an array in a collection by using `collect($array)` if that is what you're asking

Comment: @apokryfos yes, that woked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should not be returning your own collection when using Fractals. You can use `$this->collection($data)` or `$this->item($data)` for single objects or entities.

Think of your transformer as your view. In MVC, you should not be making any calculations on your view (if you can help it), that is because the view is often repeated so any calculation will be repeated unnecessarily.

The logic you need belongs in your controllers.

https://fractal.thephpleague.com/resources/